# Nested PKCS7 in BouncyCastle

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I would like to encapsulate SignedData in EnvelopedData.
I am using BouncyCastle. 
After looking in an example, I wrote something like this:

```
 CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(out.toByteArray()), true);


    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(args[3]);

    CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(inputStream);

    CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator engen = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
    engen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(certificate).setProvider("BC"));
CMSEnvelopedData envelopedData =engen.generate(  new CMSProcessableByteArray(signedData.getEncoded()),
new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES256_CBC).setProvider("BC").build());
```

But I think this is wrong. Where can I specify the ContentType of ContentInfo?  I need to specify the content type of EnvelopedData as SignedData, but it's not possible with the CMSSignedData class.